# How to order an array dependend on another array

Tags: javascript, arrays, lodash, array-splice

I have two arrays:

- values: Array with all values
- mainValues: List with the mainValues, these values exists already in array values, but have to be ordered. I.e. mainValues should be the first values in array values

I resolved this problem like this, but I'm not sure whether this is the best practise or not:

```js
var values = ['bla', 'x', 'y', 'z', 'two', 'one', 'three'];
var mainValues = ['one', 'two', 'three'];

_.forEach(mainValues.reverse(), function(val) {
    var index = _.indexOf(values, val);
    values.splice(index, 1);
    values.unshift(val);
});

console.log(values); // => ["one", "two", "three", "bla", "x", "y", "z"]
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/3.10.0/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to work well:

```js
var values = ['bla', 'x', 'y', 'z', 'two', 'one', 'three'];
var mainValues = ['one', 'two', 'three'];


result = _(mainValues).concat(_.difference(values, mainValues))

document.write(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/3.10.0/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, @georg. Can you explain why you create a lodash object with _(mainValues)? 
For mit it works also if I concatenate mainValues => mainValues.concat(_.difference(values, mainValues))

Comment: @mbppv: this will work just as fine, but I personally prefer not to mix js and underscore functions in one expression.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with the `Array.prototype.sort()` function.

```js
var values = ['bla', 'x', 'y', 'z', 'two', 'one', 'three'];
var mainValues = ['one', 'two', 'three'];

values.sort(function(obj1, obj2) {
  var idxObj1 = mainValues.reverse().indexOf(obj1);
  var idxObj2 = mainValues.reverse().indexOf(obj2);
  return idxObj2 - idxObj1;
});

console.log(values);
```

Comment: Thanks Matthias! Can you explain me why your solution is better than mine?

Comment: You are welcome! Well, I've never claimed that my approach is better than yours. Furthermore, I didn't conduct a performance test, as a consequence I cannot state the efficiency. However, I think the key advantage of my approach is that you don't need a JavaScript library to sort an array depending on another array.